# Is it ok to ask questions about client's requests versus best practices?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

Most specifically, would I be ok to ask a specific question about how others would handle a specific situation where a client wants me to implement something I think is an awful idea. My question isn't an ambiguous "What do you do when a customer asks you to do something you don't like?" Rather it's a specific question about a specific case.

Comment: You could try on programmers.stackexchange.com , but take care to read their FAQ and search for possible duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like it would almost certainly be off-topic on Stack Overflow, but you might try it out on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).  Be prepared,  because it may be closed there as well, or you might just get "that's between you and your client" answers.  As always, please read the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) and [search before posting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=client).

Comment: I hadn't seen the programmers site yet. I'll look there.